# For the inner lists break string down into 3 character acronyms

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def testing(dnaStrand):
    
protein = []

start = dnaStrand.find('ATG')
    
end = len(dnaStrand)
    
totalLength = dnaStrand[start:end]
    
remove = totalLength.split('TAG')
    
protein = [[i] for i in remove]
    
print(protein)

protein is a list of lists - Each time 'TAG' appears in the given string a new inner list is created and contains all characters up till the next 'TAG'. I want my inner lists to be groups of three characters. For example:

testing('ATGABCTAGDEFHIJTAGKLM')

returns:

[['ATGABC'], ['DEFHIJ'], ['KLM']]

What I need:

[['ATG', 'ABC'], ['DEF', 'HIJ'], ['KLM']]
```

The input can be any combination of letter, there can be unlimited inner lists and there can be unlimited items inside the inner lists.

Comment: Pls format your code properly.

Comment: Sorry had to google how to lol,  i'm a noob

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def testing(dnaStrand):
    protein=dnaStrand.split('TAG')
    for i in range(len(protein)):
        if len(protein[i]) > 3:
            protein[i]=[protein[i][:3],protein[i][3:]]
        else:
            protein[i]=[protein[i][:3]]
    print(protein)
testing('ATGABCTAGDEFHIJTAGKLM')
```

Edit:

```
def testing(dnaStrand):
    protein=dnaStrand.split('TAG')
    for i in range(len(protein)):
        if len(protein[i]) > 3:
            protein[i]=[protein[i][:3],protein[i][3:]]
        else:
            protein[i]=[protein[i][:3]]
    return protein
print(testing('ATGABCTAGDEFHIJTAGKLM'))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> [['ATG', 'ABC'], ['DEF', 'HIJ'], ['KLM']]
```

Comment: Yash Makan nothing was printed

Comment: Which python version are you using? It prints the exact output you want...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def testing(dnaStrand):
    protein = []
    start = dnaStrand.find('ATG')
    end = len(dnaStrand)
    totalLength = dnaStrand[start:end]
    remove = totalLength.split('TAG')
    for i in remove: # every item in remove
        appendlist = [i[:3],i[3:]] # split with 3 chars
        if appendlist[1] == '': # if the item is empty, 
            del appendlist[1] # delete it
        protein.append(appendlist) # then append it to protein
    print(protein)
testing('ATGABCTAGDEFHIJTAGKLM')
```

Comment: ppwater nothing printed here either.

Comment: @StephenMcM190 It's being printed for me, are you using python 3 and python IDLE?

Comment: Did you copy all of the code? and what input have you used?

Comment: @StephenMcM190 And if it's fixed, let me know.

Comment: PPwater im using python3. Your first code was correct, although when I entered a string with many more characters it only returned the final character of the string as a list.

Comment: @StephenMcM190 Did the string start with ATG?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *list comprehension*, try this instead:

```
def testing(dnaStrand):
    protein = []
    start = dnaStrand.find('ATG')
    end = len(dnaStrand)
    totalLength = dnaStrand[start:end]

    remove = totalLength.split('TAG')
    for str in remove:
        split_str = [str[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(str), 3)]
        protein.append(split_str)    
    print(protein)

testing('ATGABCTAGDEFHIJTAGKLM')
```